# Why is the Update Control of Gridview is behaving abnormally?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, model-view-controller

Here is my code for updating the gridview rows. But what it does it shows this behavior which I guess is not what it usually does. Please point out what did I do wrong.

[This is an image showcasing what is happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2lqt.png)

The code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    bindgrid();
  }
}

private void bindgrid()
{
  con.Open();

  MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "select * from vendor";

  MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Load(dr);

  GridView1.DataSource = dt;
  GridView1.DataBind();

  con.Close();
}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
  bindgrid();
}
```

And this is ASPX code:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button Text="Edit Element" CssClass="btn btn-success fa fa-edit" ID="Editbutton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-success fa fa-edit" ID="updatebutton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
    <asp:Button Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-warning fa fa-close" ID="cancelbutton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
  </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor ID">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="idlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("v_id")%>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="idtext" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("v_id")%>'></asp:TextBox>
  </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor Name">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="namelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("v_name")%>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="nametext" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("v_name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
  </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Should I add aspx too ?

Comment: Actually you have used gridview row editing event so because of that its Grid view functionality when you click on Edit it will change label to textbox and put Update and Cancel button

Comment: Now I am getting this error.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Do you have Row_Updating event?

Comment: yes i added a update event.

Comment: can you please post relevant code of aspx and update event

Comment: You can have a view at it. I have added it

Comment: where you are getting error in this code?

Comment: When I update my gridview fields

Comment: I understood Previous issue but not this.